# Why I need to specify a name when I create a new model?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm just beginning learning MongoDB and Mongoose, I can't get the point of the first argument of `model` function. Why I need to specify a string as name, and what's its purpose?

```js
// Schema
var CustomerSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

// Model, that is the constructor
var Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);

// Instance, a particular customer
var john = new Customer({});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower-cased, pluralized version of the model name is used for the name of the MongoDB collection it's associated with (e.g. `customers` in this case).

It also allows your code to look up the model by name via `mongoose.model('Customer')`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to control the way the pluralized name?

Comment: @Gremo You can override the default collection name with the third parameter to `model`.  As in:  `mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema, 'custs');`